# Articles before pōwhiri

Tags: articles

1. **A** pōwhiri may not be performed for every group of manuhiri (visitors); a mihi whakatau ("informal greeting to visitors") may be used instead.
2. Pōwhiri is often used for special visitors or for tūpāpaku (the body of the deceased) for a tangihanga (funeral). However, pōwhiri are also often performed for tourist groups as part of special events.
3. For most non-Māori speakers the wero, an aggressive challenge of the visitor at the beginning of the ceremony, is the most spectacular part of **the** pōwhiri.

Can you explain to me the usage of these articles before pōwhiri?

Comment: Since it is not an English word, it's a little hard to say.  It depends on whether you want to treat it like a general phenomenon (like, "Marriage is an institution in which...") or a specific instance (like "A marriage can be strengthened by...")

Comment: Does "the" represent the category of powhiri in the third sentence?